# Can I use 8s Claris R2000 Rear Derailleur on a 10 Speed Cogs (11-28t) and 10s drop-bar brifters/sti?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, brifters

A 8s claris roadbike derailleur on 10s cogs and Sensah Phi 10s drop-bar shifter.

Comment: What model shifters will you be using?

Comment: I'm using sensah phi shifters. 10s

Comment: Aren’t the Sensah shifters based on SRAM designs? In which case you will need a SRAM 10sp derailleur.